# Django: get all permissions on template separated by groups

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have an **admin site**, I want to edit and add roles to it.

It looks like this
[image]

I can get all the permissions using the `POST` method by calling every name but I have many **permissions** and **groups**.

But by using that I can only save one group at a time.

Is there a way to get the permissions separated by groups when the save button was clicked?

For example:

```
{'Super Admin':['permision1','permision2'], 'Admin':['permision1'], 'Subscription Manager':['permision2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the items with the permissions with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

{
    group.name: [perm.name for perm in group.permissions.all()]
    for group in Group.objects.prefetch_related('permissions')
}
```